# Не срабатывает js

Tags: html, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Есть код

```
        <input id="NameNew" type="text" value="" />
        <input id="PriceNew" type="number" value="" />
        <input id="CountNew" type="number" value="" />
        <input id="submit" type="button" value="Add" />


    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#submit').click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var name = $('#NameNew').val();
                var price = $('#PriceNew').val();
                var count = $('#CountNew').val();
                name = encodeURIComponent(name);
                $('.ListDrinks').load('@Url.Action("AddDrinkModel")?' + name + ','price+ ',' + count)
            });
        });
    </script>
```

По сути он должен при клике на кнопку брать значения с полей и отправлять в контроллер. Но нет ни ошибок, ни попытки какого-либо запроса. По-моему он вообще не видит скрипт. 
И ещё попутный вопрос - как включать ajax на последней версии jquery (3.1.1)? Просто в прежних версиях он был легко узнаваем, а тут... подключаю все что есть просто : jquery-3.1.1.js, jquery-3.1.1.intellisense, jquery-3.1.1.slim.

Comment: в параметре load должен быть валидный url (например http://ya.ru?search=opa&param2=hello) а у вас там не понятно что

Comment: информацию брал отсюда
https://metanit.com/sharp/mvc5/10.7.php

Answer (score 1):

Ошибку нашел, даже две. Во-первых, перед переменной price пропустил +. Во-вторых, забыл про имя переменной, на которую будет отправлен запрос

...("AddDrinkModel")?**model**' +...

В общем типичные ошибки новичка. Будьте внимательны, друзья)